# Firebase database set() error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I work with ReactJs and Firebase and I get an error message but all the work is apparently fine.

**The issue :**

```
export const CreateDbUser = (id, username, email) => {
  firebase.database().ref(`users/${id}`).set({
    username,
    email
  })
}
```

Here I create a database child to store different information about a user (it is just part of the info) and I get this error:

```
Object(...)(...) is undefined
TypeError: "Object(...)(...) is undefined"
```

but it all works in the real-time database

[image: snapshot]

I'd like to know why I get this error and how to resolve this because it will probably create a problem in the future.
Thank for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `username` and `email` are objects (which I suppose they aren't), you are using `set` wrong. 
Try this:

```
export const CreateDbUser = (id, username, email) => {
  firebase.database().ref(`users/${id}`).set({
    username: username,
    email: email
  })
}
```

Comment: That’s work thank’s. I forgot to try this. Thank you